# Fail to download from OSS

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

So i was following [this tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/#create-a-new-appbundle) to get used to the `Revit Design Automation API` but i am stuck now at [task 7](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/) because whenever i create [a work item](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/#step-1-create-a-workitem) it starts but if i check the status using the `activity id` i get the following error:

```
[11/21/2023 09:28:27] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:blubibla/deleteWalls'
[11/21/2023 09:28:27] Error: Failed to prepare app package(s). End of Central Directory record could not be found.
[11/21/2023 09:28:28] Error: Unable to download file from urn:adsk.objects:os.object:blubibla/deleteWalls: Fail to download from OSS: BucketName-'blubibla', ObjectKey-'deleteWalls', Error-'The operation was canceled.'.
[11/21/2023 09:28:28] Error: Fail to download from OSS: BucketName-'blubibla', ObjectKey-'deleteWalls', Error-'The operation was canceled.'
[11/21/2023 09:28:28] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
```

you can find the full log file [here](https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/test0/aac082ade9d94a79a6d9391422061394/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjELj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCICSBdu%2Ffjd88m%2BpwDNzqV50XU9wVtt9WS4npibwOahCKAiB01RZAUQBPq5n6%2FaS4%2B89d9%2Fdut2DxAHdJS%2B7YUJS4yyqAAwgREAQaDDIyMDQ3MzE1MjMxMCIM%2FHLpHW7sCBXeO%2B%2BSKt0CDo%2F3vRQF1yo4k5zZo3j%2FwtJM0%2F8f%2F14YghYG7HI2kzuy4eBac4W%2FJBJKOFJ9t4ZMFwrA%2Ber7e6qpgkbTWI245gpGzdyGHz0RkA97OPfEag90DSpL6q38sgE0zziBHTevVtq6UqlGq6PSGvaEk8KgCf2%2FfGEuF1BZMGbgjWchfcfqAytJmDDO968SHgAGJQXEbWh8yuIEnpyZKahnWlBzrvSWpOBlXjBsB85eDDyxCWDQ5fMMeA40yPnW3ztjWP6HPQhJdOQhkvG9kCvmZx2JEyopz227JQPrg51GUpJj3UsyvnSfHzBrhCI4S58PNmehxqEqoMsTE8e%2BPiORwANDYgvW7%2Bcw9ay2XMxSBF9JGhLYI8JNeswJxlax5YUmyPjMtMNpLqBuhdXA5zQ7Tzac6X9gd09jqhKeCPKMe3NSsgh7GsC%2BMZT0jlQ5IvC6vv2J7%2BFYQfJ09Skt%2F2SqDDC3ufGqBjqfAdnBKiEKhALBUb76HSWQl9CR8oJce5fpjhpiawkiiIw%2Bfa8tK2gCGDBIJFtArTm6%2BhkI8KPPRG1CGawhNd4v1McKh9UDFEeYpJzEe8Kdm7bcXnQGoc%2FGpEDnVSJ4ObBs2M3o2vQeICwSwGf2olirP2yMymEJ4Fl2%2BkIT7mh89Tkre7%2FwTBFu%2F3Jg32SNpoLHsnhDQ578JzU3gXuEWGHW%2Fg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3HRHUS3GG%2F20231121%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231121T092827Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=7805eddbddffc8aa2dd9fe214bc1c98a151b22b617c8ae0042ab165e5c6233e2) , thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The key error is this:

```
[11/21/2023 09:28:27] Error: Failed to prepare app package(s). End of Central Directory record could not be found.
```

It looks like your appbundle is bad (corrupt zip file). When we detect this error, we cancel all other downloads hence the OSS "operation was canceled" error.

Comment: i downloaded theappBundle zip file as instructed in the tutorial from https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-tutorial-postman/tree/master/DA4Revit/tutorial_data without modifying it and i still got this error

Comment: It does works at my end, can you run delete app bundle, if you are using postman collection.  refer https://pasteboard.co/Lkq7yYJhesYN.jpg