# Failed to download when requesting to Dropbox within the WorkItem created

Tags: autodesk-forge, dropbox, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation, app-bundle

I’ve tried the AU class on  [Using Design Automation for Revit for Displaying RFAs in the Forge Viewer](https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Using-Design-Automation-Revit-Displaying-RFAs-Forge-Viewer-2020) to Convert the .rfa files to .rvt files so that can be performed via Autodesk Platform Services APS (formerly Forge). Utilizing HTTP requesting via Postman and Dropbox repository for downloading the empty .rvt and .rfa files, for submitting the WorkItem in this tutorial, within the body of the request I’ve used an Oath02 type for Authorization to access the Dropbox API Arg. The response is:

```
{
    "status": "pending",
    "stats": {
        "timeQueued": "2023-12-26T07:14:25.9899257Z"
    },
    "id": "****"
}
```

But when requesting for the results of this WorkItem, the response is:

```
{
    "status": "failedDownload",
    "reportUrl": "****",
    "stats": {
        "timeQueued": "2023-12-26T07:14:25.9899257Z",
        "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-12-26T07:14:26.3170752Z",
        "timeFinished": "2023-12-26T07:14:26.9437548Z"
    },
```

And the response body of the reportedUrl in this result was:

```
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Starting work item *****
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Start download phase.
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download'
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download'
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Error: Failed to prepare app package(s). End of Central Directory record could not be found.
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Error: Unable to download file from https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download: The operation was canceled..
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Error: Unable to download file from https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download: The operation was canceled..
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
[12/26/2023 08:04:31] Job finished with result FailedDownload
```

I need to mention that I've been use the "Forge Tutorial for Postman" for creating an Appbundle instead of the instructions prepared in the  [Using Design Automation for Revit for Displaying RFAs in the Forge Viewer](https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Using-Design-Automation-Revit-Displaying-RFAs-Forge-Viewer-2020).

Also need to mention that the Dropbox files can be downloaded using HTTP request. So the problem probably is about the Appbundle I've used. Previously I used the tutorial on  [Using Design Automation for Revit for Displaying RFAs in the Forge Viewer](https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Using-Design-Automation-Revit-Displaying-RFAs-Forge-Viewer-2020) to create an Appbundle but It didn't worked.
Can I use another "ContentPackage" for this porpuse? If no, Do I need to create a Revit Plugin and then convert it to a "ContentPackage"? Or is there an easier way to create a "ContentPackage" to upload in the body of Appbunlde?
Am I missing something?

Can anybody share his/her own experience in this project for me?
I really appreciate your answers for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
[12/26/2023 08:04:30] Error: Failed to prepare app package(s). End of Central Directory record could not be found
```

Seems to be a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77524607/11057988). I suggest make sure that your upload appbundle step is accurate.